# Two different controllers in one view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a view where it has a text-editor with a content value which for **DocumentController** and text-area for **CommentController**. I wanted to post a comment within the same view. Here's my view below.

**read.blade.php**

```
<div class = "col-md-6">

    <div class = "form-group">

        <textarea id = "content">{{ $document->content }}</textarea>

    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">

        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Approve</button>

    </div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-6">
    <form class = "form-vertical" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('comments') }}">

        <div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

            <label for = "comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "4" id = "comment" placeholder = "Leave a feedback"></textarea>

            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</span>
            @endif

        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Comment</button>

        </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my function for **DocumentController** to access the content of **read.blade.php**.

```
class DocumentController extends Controller
{
//READ
public function readDocuments($id)
{
    //Find the document in the database and save as var.
    $document = Document::find($id);


    return view ('document.read')->with('document', $document);
}
}
```

**CommentController** Here when I tried to die and dump the request it only gets the request of my token but in my textarea it's not getting the value. How can I solve this problem? Any tips?

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function postComments(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
        $this->validate($request,
        [
            'comment' => 'required',
        ]);

        $commentObject = new Comment();

        $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;
        $commentObject->save();
    }
}
```

Routes for getting the content of **DocumentController**

```
Route::get('/document/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.read',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

Routes for post the content of comment using **CommentController**

```
//COMMENT

Route::post('/comments',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@postComments',
    'as' => 'comments',
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `name` attribute on your `textarea`.

Change this:

```
<textarea class = "form-control" rows = "4" id = "comment" placeholder = "Leave a feedback"></textarea>
```

To this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Leave feedback"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great!! Why do I need to put `name = "comment"` instead of `id = "comment"`? Because I already have an identifier in my textarea.

Comment: In this specific case, the difference is that HTML forms are a group of input elements with a `name` but `id` is a global element selector used primarily by CSS and JavaScript. Without a name for a field, the form does not know what to call the value so it skips it altogether.

Comment: To be clear, it is very common to have both `name` and `id` set on a form input. Every form I have worked on in recent memory had both for every element. Just remember that `id` has to be globally unique and `name` has to be unique within the form.

Comment: At first I thought you can use `id` to get the requested input. Now it's clear to me. Thanks to you bro! Godbless :)